# How to customize Subscription contributor role for blocking Storage in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-policy, azure-rbac

I have a requirement to customize the contributor role at Azure Subscription level, such that, people added to that customized contributor role can NOT view or read the data from the storage account (under that subscription).

This is how i'm doing this:

Step1
[image: Clone Subscription contributor Basic]

Step2
[image: Permission]

Step3 ( Actions shows * )
[image: JSON]

[image: Review and Create]

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) MSFT link does NOT show me the JSON details that can be removed or added so that the read access to the storage account can be **blocked**.

Hence, I'm trying below ways to customize this (two assignable scopes to cover subscription as well as block viewing the storage data):

[image: 2 assignable scope]

Note, The idea is to People need a contributor role to manage the subscription. However, they *MUST NOT* view the data from the storage under this particular subscription.

I think this is not the right approach. Are there any other ways to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a [custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles), then you should have a look at the [resource provider operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftstorage). From there, you can see all the available actions per resource provider.

You would probably be interested in the `DataActions` such as `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers/blobs/read` and others depending on what you want to filter out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block particularly  Azure Storage under **Subscription** Scope Level.

Kindly **Exclude** Azure Storage under Add Permission Section in order to block Azure Storage only while creating **RBAC** Role